# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have parameter passing in console shows as:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Oj9EGihSOwgdXGLLQWqVESYMP/N4K0KzDS4KyVhWXPg=", "rfp"=>{"user_id"=>"", "client_id"=>"", "othercms"=>"", "otherecommerce"=>"", "numberofpage"=>"", "designcomplexity"=>"", "browser"=>"", "nuhacks"=>"", "nujavascript"=>"", "numberofmenu"=>"", "designpages"=>"", "designformobilepages"=>"", "framworks"=>"", "test_report_ids"=>[""], " payment_gateway_ids"=>[""], "payment_gateway_ids"=>["2"], "**payment_gateways"=>{"name"=>"slsk"}**, "commit"=>"Create Rfp", "project_id"=>"18"}
```

**Controller**:

```
@rfp = Rfp.new(params[:rfp])

if [:payment_gateway][:name]
  @pm=PaymentGateway.new([:payment_gateways][:name])
end
```

as payment gateway is independent model:

Even though paymengt gateway name passing in params it shows above error. What is missing? Please give me any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you dont understand data types.
On first line, you initialized new instance of Rfp class, and then you are trying to retrieve index of nothing, instead of array or hash.
There are two solutions for this.

1. I noticed that payment_gateways are inside rfp parameters, so i guess its association or attribute of it, so you can check "show me all the names of payment_gateways in newly initialized object"

   `if @rfp.payment_gateways.map(&:name).any?`
2. Check in params:

   `if params[:rfp].present? and params[:rfp][:payment_gateways].present? and params[:rfp][:payment_gateways][:name].present?`

After that, initialize your PaymentGateway instance:

```
`@pm = PaymentGateway.new(params[:rfp][:payment_gateways])`
```

Comment: this was the missing !!

Answer (score 1):

As per your code it should be `if params[:rfp][:payment_gateways][:name]` not `if  [:payment_gateway][:name]`

So It should look like

as your incomplete params there is `rfp` as well so it might be `params[:rfp][:payment_gateways][:name]`

```
    if params[:rfp][:payment_gateways][:name]
      @pm=PaymentGateway.new(params[:rfp][:payment_gateways][:name])
    end
```

or inliner

```
 @pm=PaymentGateway.new(params[:rfp][:payment_gateways][:name]) if params[:rfp][:payment_gateways][:name]
```

Comment: This gives TypeError (can't convert Symbol into Integer):

Comment: `[:payment_gateways][:name]` this not valid ruby expression. this raise exeption.

Comment: shouldnt it be params[:payment_gateways][:name]

Comment: @user944938 I did before your comment :)

Comment: `if [:payment_gateways][:name]` this too

Comment: `params[:payment_gateways][:name]` raise exeption if `params[:payment_gateways][:name]` haven `:payment_gateways` key

Comment: @Rajashri Das.. Im glad you did.. Its the basics

Comment: @user944938 yes I know I overlooked the mistake

Comment: try look inside the params variable `params.inspect`

Comment: @Monk_Code Actually `[:payment_gateways][:name]` *is* a valid Ruby expression; just not one you'd likely need under normal circumstances. It's roughly equivalent to `Array(:payment_gateways).[](:name)`. (Create a new array with `:payment_gateways` in it, and call it's `[]` method with `:name`.)

Comment: open `irb` console and try `[:payment_gateways][:name]`, this raise exeption

Comment: @RajarshiDas thats it!

Comment: @Monk_Code same error as in my first comment!!in rails console

Comment: @pm = PaymentGateway.new(params[:rfp][:payment_gateways])  This solve my problem..

Answer (score 0):

In Controller, it should be:

```
@rfp = Rfp.new(params[:rfp])

if params[:payment_gateway]
  @pm=PaymentGateway.new(params[:payment_gateways][:name])
end
```

or even better

```
@rfp = Rfp.new(params[:rfp])

@pm=PaymentGateway.new(params[:payment_gateways][:name]) unless params[:payment_gateway].nil?
```

also check, whether it should be `params[:payment_gateway]` or `params["payment_gateway"]`.

Comment: why you skip to check name in params if it was nil then

Comment: It really depends on usecase, if nil is not allowed in `PaymentGateway.new` function, in that case `if` condition should be `params[:payment_gateway] && params[:payment_gateways][:name]`.